# How can I get my Material UI cards to wrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am transforming my divs to Material UI card component. I am having difficulties spacing the cards. I have 4 cards in a div I want them to be spaced evenly. I achieved this when they were just plain divs.

```js
export default function ({ images }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={cardStyles.container}>
        <div className={cardStyles.album}>
          <img className={cardStyles.img} src="yellowCabbin.jpg" />
          <Typography className={cardStyles.description}>
            <h1>Fall Cabbin in Tunisia</h1>
            <p>
              Bautiful cabbin in Tunisian country side by a river. Quiet place
              and abudance of nature ready to be explored by you and your family
            </p>
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <div className={cardStyles.album2}>
          {images.map((image) => (
            <Card
              className={cardStyles.card}
              sx={{ maxWidth: 345, m: -0.2, p: 1 }}
            >
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  key={image.id}
                  image={image.url}
                  alt={image.id}
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography className={cardStyles.description}>
                    <h1>{image.id}</h1>
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    /* column-gap: 8px; */
    padding-top:32px;
    margin: 0px 120px 0px 120px;
    /* background-color: brown; */

}

.album{
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 8px;
    object-fit: contain;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.album2{
    /* padding: 8px; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.card{
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    /* padding: 0px; */
    z-index: 2;
    
}

.img:hover, .card:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    z-index: 3;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    
}

.description{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1),70%);

}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){
    .container{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .album{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .album2{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[image] this is how it looks. I want the 4 images on the right to be spaced evenly.

i tried using sx={m:1} it pushes everything into a single column, i also tried sx={p:8} it does nothing

[image]

Comment: Please show us rendered HTML in a snippet demo. It's very difficult to work with JSX for CSS issues.

Comment: How do i do that ? I fixed one of the problem. The other problem is the spacing between the cards

Comment: It's in the browser. :)

Answer (score 0):

First take care of the height:

```
.album2{
    /* padding: 8px; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

It would be better not to use auto but a fixed length as you know the height of each element height is 600px. Add this attribute:

```
justify-content:space-evenly
```